# How do I load a dataset into other cells based on the values in the first cell of the table QTableWidget?

Tags: python, pyqt5, qtablewidget

The user drives data into the first cell of the table, which is pulled up from the database by autocomplete. But how do I know that he has finished editing?
Is it necessary for me to take the data from this cell and upload the remaining data to the other cells?

```
class MasterWorkPlace(QMainWindow):
# Master work place
def __init__(self, what_post, parent=None, flag=Qt.Window):
    super().__init__(parent, flag)
    uic.loadUi('ui/work_place_for_master.ui', self)
    self.blanks_operations = ["Clean", "Cut", "Pl", "Angle cut", "Drill"]
    self.postion_cell_box = QtWidgets.QComboBox()
    self.what_post = what_post
    self.what_job = ''.join(db.get_job_by_post(self.what_post)[0])
    self.what_operat = ''.join(db.get_job_by_post(self.what_post)[1])
    self.post_lbl.setText(self.what_post)
    self.dateEdit.setDate(QtCore.QDate.currentDate())  # Setup current date
    self.dateEdit.setDisplayFormat('dd.MM.yyyy')  # Date format
    self.how_many_columns = 0
    self.load_table_clmn()
    self.add_str_btn.clicked.connect(self.add_str_to_table)  # Add str to table
    self.main_table.itemChanged.connect(self.load_information_from_db)

def load_table_clmn(self):
    # Load header to table
    if self.what_operat in self.blanks_operations:
        name_of_colmns = ["Pos", "Material", "Massa kg", "Done",
                          "Plan", "Total", "Remains"]
    self.how_many_columns = len(name_of_colmns)
    self.main_table.setColumnCount(self.how_many_columns)
    self.main_table.setHorizontalHeaderLabels(name_of_colmns)
    self.main_table.horizontalHeaderItem(0).setTextAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignVCenter
                                                             | QtCore.Qt.AlignHCenter)
    for evr_column in range(0, self.how_many_columns):
        self.main_table.horizontalHeaderItem(evr_column).setTextAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignVCenter
                                                                          | QtCore.Qt.AlignHCenter)
        if evr_column == 0:
            self.main_table.setColumnWidth(evr_column, 90)
        else:
            self.main_table.setColumnWidth(evr_column, 120)

def add_str_to_table(self):
    # Add str to a table
    quantity_clmn = self.str_to_table_sb.value()
    postion_cell = QtWidgets.QLineEdit()
    autocomplite_list = []
    how_much_rows_was = self.main_table.rowCount()
    for information in db.get_all_operations():
        autocomplite_list.append(information[1])
    for _ in range(0, quantity_clmn):
        rowposition = self.main_table.rowCount()
        self.main_table.insertRow(rowposition)
    self.add_autocomplite_to_table(how_much_rows_was)
    self.str_to_table_sb.setValue(1)

def add_autocomplite_to_table(self, last_row):
    column = 0
    not_edit_columns = [1, 2, 5, 6, 7]
    if self.what_operat not in self.blanks_operations:
        not_edit_columns = [1, 4, 5, 6]
    for row in range(last_row, self.main_table.rowCount()):
        # postion_cell = QtWidgets.QLineEdit()
        done_cell_sb = QtWidgets.QSpinBox()
        done_cell_sb_2 = QtWidgets.QSpinBox()
        done_cell_sb.setMinimum(1)
        done_cell_sb_2.setMinimum(1)
        done_cell_sb.setMaximum(1000)
        done_cell_sb_2.setMaximum(1000)
        autocomplite_list = []
        for information in db.get_all_operations():
            autocomplite_list.append(information[1])
            self.postion_cell_box.addItem(information[1])
        self.postion_cell_box.setEditable(True)
        # completer = QCompleter(autocomplite_list, postion_cell)
        # postion_cell.setCompleter(completer)
        for column in range(self.how_many_columns):
            if column == 0:
                self.main_table.setCellWidget(row, column, self.postion_cell_box)
            elif column in not_edit_columns:
                delegate = ReadOnlyDelegate(self.main_table)
                self.main_table.setItemDelegateForColumn(column, delegate)
            elif column == 3:
                self.main_table.setCellWidget(row, column, done_cell_sb_2)
            else:
                self.main_table.setCellWidget(row, column, done_cell_sb)

def load_information_from_db(self):
    if self.main_table.selectedIndexes():
        row = self.main_table.currentIndex().row()
        name_of_posit = self.main_table.model().index(row, 0).data()
        print(name_of_posit)
```

I tried to use the "itemChanged" method for QTableWidget, but I failed because I used different widgets (QComboBox) in the table.
Also I saw pastes about QAbstractItemDelegate.closeEditor() method, but I didn't understand how to connect this for my widgets.

Thank u for any help :)

Answer (score 1):

Index widgets ("cell widgets" for QTableWidget) are not normally intended to allow interaction with the data model. They are just "overlaid" widgets that possibly know nothing about the underlying model.

If you need to show the editor even when the user doesn't explicitly start editing the cell, then you need to call [`openPersistentEditor()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtablewidget.html#openPersistentEditor).

Note that Qt creates the editors based on the data type, meaning that you first need to properly set the value using the correct type. QTableWidgetItem does not accept numeric values in its constructor, so you need to call `setData(Qt.DisplayRole, value)` and add the item to the table before opening the editor.

If you need more control over the editor (like setting its range), then you have to create your own delegate and override [`createEditor()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstyleditemdelegate.html#createEditor):

```py
class LimitSpinBoxDelegate(QStyledItemDelegate):
    def createEditor(self, parent, option, index):
        editor = super().createEditor(parent, option, index)
        if isinstance(editor, QSpinBox):
            editor.setRange(1, 1000)
        return editor
```

Then set the delegate for the columns in which you expect numeric values and want to limit the range:

```py
class MasterWorkPlace(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, what_post, parent=None, flag=Qt.Window):
        # ...
        self.spinBoxDelegate = LimitSpinBoxDelegate(self.main_table)
        self.main_table.setItemDelegateForColumn(someColumn, self.spinBoxDelegate)
```

Doing the above allows you to directly use the view's functions (including the `itemChanged` signal) and access the data from the model instead of trying to get it from the widget.

Note: you should only create new delegates if their instances are to be kept separated (for example, differentiate the possible spinbox range in the constructor), otherwise you should only do that when having different views, as item delegates cannot be shared between views. This means that creating a new `ReadOnlyDelegate` in that for loop is not only pointless, but also wrong:

- considering that that loop is also nested, it is useless to call `setItemDelegateForColumn()` multiple for each row;
- based on your code, the "read only" columns can change depending on context, but once a delegate is set on a column (or row), it's set for the *whole* column, meaning that a previously set read only column will still be read only unless you reset the delegate;
- objects created with a parent constructor will be persistent (and occupy memory) until the parent exists, even if unused; you're potentially creating hundreds or thousands of delegates that you're not even using;

If you want to prevent editing of specific items, then create the item and remove the `Qt.ItemIsEditable` flag:

```py
item = QTableWidgetItem()
item.setFlags(item.flags() & ~Qt.ItemIsEditable)
self.main_table.setItem(row, column, item)
```

Comment: Thanks for your advice about ReadOnlyDelegate, I'll fix it. So about widgets in a QTableWidget:  I'm interesting only in  if user change first column(it means QComboBox), because then I can load a data from database to others cells.  So when the user finishes editing the combobox info, I want to take this text and search for data in the database to upload to other cells.

Comment: In your code there's only one QComboBox and it's also unclear where you want to place it, since it's also in a nested for loops, which doesn't make a lot of sense, since a widget cannot exist in multiple places. Besides, if you want to use the combo to show the results of a search within a table, that combo should probably *not* be in the table.